# Creating foreign key requires ENGINE keyword to be included in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql

My server data .. Ubuntu - NGINX - MySQL

I need to create a table in wordpress database with a foreign key with wp_posts table .. but I noticed that to create a foreign key in the new table I must include ENGINE keyword into **create table** statement, I don't know why but creating foreign key failed when ENGINE keyword not included.

Of course I need this statement to be programmatically for my clients so I cannot include ENGINE='USER DB ENGINE' .. So Is there anyway to use the default database engine?

P.S. I should include ENGINE keyword.

Comment: Can you write down a comment before down vote please to understand I'm not a professional in MySQL .. I ask a question to get help not to get rate

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports foreign keys only for specific database engines. The two most commonly used and present in an installation are:

- MyISAM
- InnoDB

InnoDB supports foreign key constraints, MyISAM does not. It is somewhere on the to do list to implement foreign key constraints in MyISAM, however nobody got to that in the last 15 years (plus/minus a few).

Comment: Thanks for your help pal, But my database engine is MYISAM, I created a new table has a foreign key but I didn't write ENGINE keyword and it failed but after some tests I include ENGINE=MYISAM in create table statement and the foreign key added successfully

Comment: It "works" but it doesn't actually do anything. [*"For storage engines that do not support foreign keys (such as MyISAM), MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key specifications."*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)